# Перехватить событие на динамическое изменение textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите как можно перехватить изменения в textarea, добавленные туда динамически?

пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#area').on('input', function () {
   $('#log').html($('#area').val());
  })
  
  $('#editor').on('input', function () {
   $('#area').val($('#editor').val());
  })
});
```

```css
#log, #editor, #area {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>area:</label><br>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<label>editor:</label><br>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<label>log:</label><br>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: никак, при установке значения из скрипта события не вызываются. Но можно при установке самому вызвать событие

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно триггерить событие когда вводят данные в другой инпут, вот так:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#area').on('input', function () {
   $('#log').html($('#area').val());
  })
  
  $('#editor').on('input', function () {
   $('#area').val($('#editor').val()).trigger('input');
  })
});
```

```css
#log {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>area:</label><br>
<textarea id="area" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<label>editor:</label><br>
<textarea id="editor" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<label>log:</label><br>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Но не уверен что это то что вы хотели.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хотелось бы конечно изолировать логику между editor и area, но как вариант, почему бы и нет.

Answer (score 0):

On change событие должно помочь http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onchange